# Can I get the private key for the JWT from Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito, private-key

I am aware that Cognito uses RSA256 and the tokens can be verified with the public key. But I need the private key because I would like to build my own authentication service, and I am managing some crucial user information through a 3rd party (web3auth), and it requires the exact same public key to not lose that specific user's information, hence I should continue authenticating my users with the use of that private key to not lose previous user information on the 3rd party.

Comment: Die you find an answer to this?

Comment: @jns_ai_unr It seems like they do not provide the private key out of box. But if they are creating a private key per user pool, they could be OK to provide it if you contact them. I found a different way to handle my problem hence I didn't pursue the question further.